target frame detached . Can not Run two feature file in one time
Failed scenarios:[0m
[31mUserRegistration.feature:3 [0m# Scenario: Verify user signup
2 Scenarios ([31m1 failed[0m, [32m1 passed[0m)
8 Steps ([31m1 failed[0m, [36m1 skipped[0m, [32m6 passed[0m)
0m27.553s
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: no such window: target window already closed
from unknown error: web view not found ----I want to print log in and sign up both in one time but can not print sign up. I feel that it can not took both window together.
